# Xaml BackGround Image

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I am writing my first Win 8.1 App and I am trying to set background image for Hubapp Layout.
I can see the background in the preview, but once I run the application it became black background.

Here is my code:

```XMAL
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Hub x:Name="Hub" x:Uid="Hub" Header="The Header">
            <Hub.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="None" 
                            ImageSource="Assets\background.png"
                            AlignmentY="Top" AlignmentX="Center"/>
            </Hub.Background>
          </Hub>
    </Grid>
```

I tried also to set the background using `ThemeResource` but I got the same result only black background

```Xaml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <Hub x:Name="Hub" x:Uid="Hub" Header="The Header">
         Background="{ThemeResource HubBackgroundImageBrush}">              </Hub>
  </Grid>
```

here is the Resources code

```Xaml
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                    <ImageBrush x:Key="HubBackgroundImageBrush" ImageSource="Assets\background.png"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>

                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                    <ImageBrush x:Key="HubBackgroundImageBrush" ImageSource="{x:Null}"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>

            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary>
     </Application.Resources>
```

Would you please tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just looked into this and it appears the background of the hub doesn't appear until a HubSection is added. 
If I try

```
<Hub x:Name="hub" Background="Red">
</Hub>
```

No Background appears despite the Hub appearing to stretch to the whole screen
but if I add a HubSection

```
<Hub x:Name="hub" Background="Red">
    <HubSection></HubSection>
 </Hub>
```

Red Background appears.

Comment: I already have 2 sections but still no background. I forgot to mention when I user color background like Background="Red". its works fine. it seems something wrong with Asset folder....